# using precompiled library packages

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, aptitude

I figured the following out the hard way, because I didn't know what resource to look at. **What should I have read?**

I used aptitude to install the c++ library package libexample5.3 and libexample5.3-dev

- libexample5.3 puts the actual object file (`libexample.so.5.3`) in `/usr/lib/`
- libexample5.3-dev puts header file(s) (`example.h`) in `/usr/include/`

To link libexample into test.cpp, compile with:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lexample
```

But first all the entities linked to must be declared:

```
#include <example.h> //contains declarations of everything provided by libexample
int main() {
    return example::CONSTANT_2;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am asking what resource I should have looked in to discover the above information.

Comment: I suppose that you can find it in the Debian/Ubuntu manual/wiki/whatever, but that's fairly standard on a UNIX system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `libexample`/`libexample-dev` stuff, the position of shared libraries and the like see the [Debian policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#s-sharedlibs-dev); for the working of the `-l` flag, see the [g++ manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++); for the fact that you have to `#include` some header to use a library, that's usual practice, but it's usually documented anyway in the library documentation.